# Blender 2.79 to 2.8 Menu problem

Tags: modeling

I made a model in Blender 2.79 and would like to modify it in Blender 2.8. I can open the project in 2.8, but can't seem to find this feature:

[image: Viewport Shading]

When I open up Blender 2.8 without opening my 2.79 project, I can find the feature. Help!

Comment: It is not advised to jump versions within the same project

Comment: Will it work tho'?

Comment: If you are loading the UI from the 2.79 file, look at the bottom of the 3dview. In recent 2.80 builds, there is now a preference to [choose the header position](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/preferences/interface.html) used so you can set headers to always be on top.

Answer (score 1):

Try to uncheck Load UI before you open the project in 2.80

[image]

Hope that helps.

Good Luck